# How to install or use yo generator-jhipster 2.0 (the new branch 2.0)

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator, jhipster

I'm new to `npm`, `yo` and this mega hipster staff.
I want to test the new branch 2.0, because I saw and error will trying the [jhipster-sample-app-2.0](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-2.0). In concrete an anjular-ui-router javascript can not we loaded.

How can I do something like `npm install -g generator-jhipster@2.0` to test the new version and try to fix this bug or improve the generated code?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The v2.0 is now merged into the master branch
- You must clone it and do a "npm link" as explained in the [Yeoman documentation](http://yeoman.io/authoring/index.html)

Comment: First of all thanks @julien-dubois.
Just if someone needs to do it inside the docker container.

First I cloned the repo executing in `/home/jhipster`  `git clone https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster.git`. After that enter inside the freshly cloned repo and execute `npm link`. 
From now you are using the latest generator. 
That's all folks.
PD: I'm planing to create provide an improve for the docker container to structure it like [link](https://bitbucket.org/EdBoraas/apache-docker/src/7d32b326a83922b4d3e62e7b4d08f194c6ef0baa/apache/?at=master)